# PyGtk: Run gtk.main() loop in a seperate thread

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

Below code is getting struck after the declaration og gtkLoopTHread itself, even though I am not giving gtkMainLoop.start() function call.
I want to run the timer in background and do some stuff in that UI and destroy the UI once the timer reaches '0'.

**Code**

```
def createCountDown(maxSec):
  while maxSec > 0:
    print maxSec;
    maxSec = maxSec - 1;

  gtk.main_quit();
  return;

maxSec = 5;
gtkLoopThread = threading.Thread(group=None, target=gtk.main, name=None, args=(), kwargs={});
print "After gtkThread declaration"
myThread = threading.Thread(group=None, target=createCountDown, name=None, args=(maxSec), kwargs={});
gtkLoopThread.start();
myThread.start();
```

**Expected Output:**

```
After gtkThread declaration
5
4
3
2
1
```

**Current behaviour:**
Line '*After gtkThread declaration*' print is not seen since gtkLoopThread starts immediately after initializing gtkLoopThread variable

Comment: No, you can't run `gtk.main()` on a different thread from your other GTK+ code. You'll need to run your other stuff on a separate thread. You also can't run `gtk.main_quit()` on a separate thread; you'll need to use `glib.idle_add()` to queue a function to run on the GTK+ thread. Sorry.

Comment: If you just want a timer, you can also use `glib.timeout_add()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues that prevent your code from running correctly.

First and foremost, you are missing the call to `gobject.threads_init()` (after `import gobject`) at the beginning of your program. This call causes PyGTK to release the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294402/1600898) when entering the main loop. Failure to call it will make threads useless. (In the latest PyGObject with Python 3, this is [no longer necessary.](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading))

The second problem, and this one is trivial, is that you are incorrectly constructing a one-element tuple for use as the `args` argument to the `threading.Thread` constructor - it should be `args=(maxSec,)`, not `args=(maxSec)`.

After the above two changes, your program displays the expected output.

Finally, [as andlabs points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700140/pygtk-run-gtk-main-loop-in-a-seperate-thread#comment59078602_35700140) and the [documentation confirms](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html), it is not allowed to call GTK code from any thread other than the thread that runs the main loop. Instead of invoking GTK functions, the worker threads can use `gobject.idle_add` to schedule code to be executed in the GUI thread. (If the GUI thread is idle, as it should be, this will happen promptly.) In other words, you should replace `gtk.main_quit()` with `gobject.idle_add(gtk.main_quit)`. If the or function takes arguments, use `gobject.idle_add(lambda: gtk_call_here(...)` instead. While it is perfectly legitimate to create multiple worker threads in a GTK program, they **must** stay clear of direct calls into GTK.

Also, according to the documentation, the thread that runs the main loop should be the same thread that initializes GTK. Thus a correct program should not `import gtk` (which initializes it) before the GUI thread is started. Here is a version of your code that implements this:

```
import threading

# Event marking the GUI thread as having imported GTK.  GTK must not
# be imported before this event's flag is set.
gui_ready = threading.Event()

def run_gui_thread():
    import gobject
    gobject.threads_init()
    import gtk
    gui_ready.set()
    gtk.main()

gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_gui_thread)
gui_thread.start()

# wait for the GUI thread to initialize GTK
gui_ready.wait()

# it is now safe to import GTK-related stuff
import gobject, gtk

def countdown(maxSec):
    while maxSec > 0:
        print maxSec
        maxSec -= 1

    gobject.idle_add(gtk.main_quit)

worker = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(5,))
print 'starting work...'
worker.start()

# When both the worker and gui_thread finish, the main thread
# will exit as well.
```